# Utilizar ":last-child:after" no Internet Explorer 8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Tenho um gráfico em que alguns elementos são gerados via CSS, nomeadamente o traço por baixo da escala de quantidade:

[image: Captura de Tela]

**CSS Utilizado:**

```css
#results .chart-scale li{
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:18px;
    padding-top:38px;
    font-family:'latolight', sans-serif;
    position:relative;
}
#results .chart-scale li:after{
    content: "";
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    width:28px;
    background-color:#0d3e38;
    opacity:0.3;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:-14px;
}
#results .chart-scale li:last-child:after{
    background-color:transparent;
}
```

## Problema

Em navegadores antigos como é o caso do IE8, a última declaração `li:last-child:after` onde retido a cor do fundo para a quantidade inicial que é zero, sendo representada como vazio no gráfico não funciona:

[image: Captura Tela IE8]

## Pergunta

[Exemplo no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/rwLW5/)

Como posso lidar com a utilização da declaração de CSS `:last-child:after` no Internet Explorer 8 ?

<sup>Se relevante, o gráfico já faz uso de jQuery, pelo que uma solução recorrendo ao uso de JavaScript também é viável.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer essa declaração de css através do Jquery:

```js
$('#results .chart-scale li:last-child:after').css('background-color','transparent');
```